# How do i remove these splotches from my rendered image?

Tags: rendering, texturing, denoise, noise-reduction

I am a beginner that just did the doughnut tutorial[image]

Comment: Looks like another mesh is breaking through the surface. Check to make sure that is not happening.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 Thank you! how do i stop the mesh from breaking though the surface?

Comment: i checked and it seems the mesh isn't breaking through the surface